# Segmentation fault comes and goes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have two rails projects on my machine. If I go directly to one of the apps and run the `rails s`, I get a seg fault error (below).

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

However if I run the other project first, then run this project, the problem goes away and the server boots up. Anyone know why this would happen or have any ideas that I could try?

I have a feeling it has to do with bundler and potentially rvm with managing gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says it is a bug, and you are using an outdated patchlevel from ruby.

Try to update to the latest patch level (I believe ruby-1.9.3-p429), and if it persists and you really trust your hardware, you will have to open a bug for ruby.

Could be computer memory issue too, I suppose it is better try your code in other box, just to be sure.